# How can I create DB table in Trait?

Tags: laravel-5, schema, eloquent

I have created a trait that creates a table in the database if it doesn't exist.
the table is created perfectly in the DB but I get an error. The error is throw by Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php

TRAIT:

```
namespace App\Traits;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

trait Translatable{

    //CREATE LANGUAGES TABLE IF DOES NOT EXIST
    public function createTranslationTable()
    {
        //ADD LANGUAGES TABLE IF DOES NOT EXIST
        if(Schema::hasTable('languages') === false){
            Schema::create('languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('language');
                $table->string('slug');
            });
        }

        //CREATE TRANSLATION TABLE IF DOES NOT EXIST
        if(Schema::hasTable('translations') === false){
            Schema::create('translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('model');
                $table->string('language_id');
                $table->foreign('language_id')->references('id')->on('languages')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->string('field_name');
                $table->string('field_translation');
            });
        }
    }

    public function translateMe()
    {
        $this->createTranslationTable;
    }

}
```

ERROR:

```
App\User::createTranslationTable must return a relationship instance.
```

I am using a trait because I want it to be able to use it with any model like so for eaxample:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Translatable;

    /**
    * Call Translatable.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->translateMe();
    }

     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
     protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
     ];

     /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
     protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
     ];

    /**
    * The attributes that are translatable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $translatableItems = [
        'name'
    ];


}
```

Comment: Can I ask why working with traits when you've got migrations?

Comment: Also, we need to know what's translatableItems. Have you tried printing what's $column? Because the upper code seems ok

Comment: I have edited my question. $translatableItems is an array of fields created in the model. So the trait knows which column to add in the table.

Comment: so you want any model able to create a table? Can I ask why? curious

Comment: are you using the facades on the trait? use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

Comment: what's the return of parent::getTable()? The code seems fine, it's a matter of finding what's missing to it and what you'll want to do with it

Comment: @abr This is my approach for having a multilingual application. In this case parent::getTable() return 'users'. And yes I am including :use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

Comment: I have updated my code above but still having same error.

Comment: Try adding extends Migration to the trait, add a Up() and Down() method. I honestly can't figure out whats wrong sorry. I'd probably setup tables up from the start, but depends on what you're trying to aim at. best of luck

Comment: @abr Migration is not a trait so Translatable cannot extend it?

Comment: Give it a shot, use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;   and extending it. I've never tried but look it up @ laravel's documentation.   https://laravel.com/api/5.5/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it was one simple one.
In the Translatable trait I was calling createTranslationTable method as a property instead then a method. so just adding the two parentesis fixed it.

BEFORE:

```
public function translateMe()
{
    $this->createTranslationTable;
}
```

NOW:

```
public function translateMe()
{
    $this->createTranslationTable();
}
```